# SQL Most recently updated row

Tags: sql

I am pulling information from an SQL database but it displays all lines various times because of multiple updates.
i have managed to eliminate duplicate using the distinct function however still shows multiple lines for the changes.

i.e.

original Qty = 4
update 1 Qty = 5
update 2 Qty = 6

All i want is the most recent update each line which is column **OLLNID**

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    OLMCU,
    OLKCOO,
    OLDOCO,
    OLDCTO,
    Date( OLTRDJ, CYYDDD ) AS OLTRDJ,
    OLLNID AS OLLNID_1, 
    OLDSC1,
    OLDSC2 AS OLDSC2_1,
    OLUOM,
    OLUORG,
    OLPRRC,
    OLAEXP,
    OLANBY 
FROM 
    E1PDES01.PRODDTA.F43199 F43199 
WHERE 
    OLMCU = '13248'
    AND Date( OLTRDJ, CYYDDD ) >= '01/01/2017'
    AND OLDCTO = 'OP'
    AND OLDOCO = 13484379 
ORDER BY 
    6
```

Comment: what flavor of sql?

Comment: ORDER BY ordinal position has been deprecated since last millenium. (1992?) Do `ORDER BY OLLNID_1` instead.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: When you are using an DISTINCT, then there are differences between those multiple lines. Which of those lines do you prefer and where are the differences. An example is useful.

Comment: Explain more about OLLNID. Which type is that? Date? Are all other rows exactly the same values for the mentioned "multiple lines"?

Comment: basically this is pulling from an Oracle/SQL server via a program called "Showcase Query" which uses SQL statements, i wasn't sure how different of a situation it would be..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like subkonstrukt I am guessing what you really want.
In case that you want the latest results by OLLNID (which is then e.g. a date), then you could group by all other values (when they differ) and choose the max OLLNID.

```
SELECT
    OLMCU,
    OLKCOO,
    OLDOCO,
    OLDCTO,
    Date(OLTRDJ, CYYDDD) AS OLTRDJ,
    MAX(OLLNID) AS OLLNID_1,
    OLDSC1,
    OLDSC2 AS OLDSC2_1,
    OLUOM,
    OLUORG,
    OLPRRC,
    OLAEXP,
    OLANBY
FROM E1PDES01.PRODDTA.F43199 F43199
WHERE OLMCU = '13248'
      AND Date(OLTRDJ, CYYDDD) >= '01/01/2017'
      AND OLDCTO = 'OP'
      AND OLDOCO = 13484379
GROUP BY
    OLMCU,
    OLKCOO,
    OLDOCO,
    OLDCTO,
    OLTRDJ,
    OLDSC1,
    OLDSC2,
    OLUOM,
    OLUORG,
    OLPRRC,
    OLAEXP,
    OLANBY;
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what SQL Flavor you´re using this might not work, also I am made some wild assumptions on your data so if you could supply more information (maybe schema / types, SQL Flavor, maybe two or three dummy rows) I will edit my answer

```
 SELECT   
    org.OLMCU,
    org.OLKCOO,
    org.OLDOCO,
    org.OLDCTO,
    Date(org.OLTRDJ, CYYDDD ) AS OLTRDJ,
    org.OLLNID AS OLLNID_1, 
    org.OLDSC1,
    org.OLDSC2 AS OLDSC2_1,
    org.OLUOM,
    org.OLUORG,
    org.OLPRRC,
    org.OLAEXP,
    org.OLANBY 
FROM 
    E1PDES01.PRODDTA.F43199 F43199 as org
LEFT OUTER JOIN E1PDES01.PRODDTA.F43199 F43199 aux ON org.OLLNID = aux.OLLNID AND org.OLLNID < aux.OLLNID
WHERE 
    org.OLMCU = '13248'
    AND Date( org.OLTRDJ, CYYDDD ) >= '01/01/2017'
    AND org.OLDCTO = 'OP'
    AND org.OLDOCO = 13484379 
    AND aux.OLLNID IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    org.OLMCU,
    org.OLKCOO,
    org.OLDOCO,
    org.OLDCTO,
    Date(org.OLTRDJ, CYYDDD ) AS OLTRDJ,
    org.OLLNID AS OLLNID_1, 
    org.OLDSC1,
    org.OLDSC2 AS OLDSC2_1,
    org.OLUOM,
    org.OLUORG,
    org.OLPRRC,
    org.OLAEXP,
    org.OLANBY 
ORDER BY org.OLLNID
```